# Python -- Having trouble parsing list data that I have where if it finds a specific letter within that list data, deletes the variable

Tags: python

Took on a personal web scraping project to teach myself python but am having trouble parsing list data that I have where if it finds a specific letter within that list data, deletes the variable.

Here is the code that I have pertaining to this:

```
age_sex = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="lh-copy truncate silver"]')

link_list = []
sex_list = []

for ii in age_sex:

          link = ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href')
          link_list.append(link)

          sex = ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//span').text
          sex_list.append(sex)

           print (link_list[0:3]
           print (sex_list[0:3]

           link_list[0] = https://www.google.com/page1, 
           link_list[1] = https://www.google.com/page2,
           link_list[2] = https://www.google.com/page3
           sex_list [0] = 42CD/TV more arbitrary information
           sex_list [1] = 30F  other arbitrary information
           sex_list [2] = 40M no info
```

What I am trying to do is for my script to search through sex_list and if it finds the letter 'F" in the third letter of sex_list[#], it deletes that person's information from sex_list[] and the corresponding link_list[].

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
age_sex = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="lh-copy truncate silver"]')

link_sex_candidates = (
    (
        ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href'),
        ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//span').text
    )
    for ii in age_sex
)
link_sex_filtered = [
    (link, sex)
    for link, sex in link_sex_candidates
    if sex[2:3] != 'F'
]
link_list = [link for link, sex in link_sex_filtered]
sex_list = [sex for link, sex in link_sex_filtered]
```

Comment: I believe you may have done the opposite of what I was looking for, "What I am trying to do is for my script to search through sex_list and if it finds the letter 'F" in the third letter of sex_list[#], it deletes that person's information from sex_list[] and the corresponding link_list[]."

Comment: Your code would return all link_list values that contain "F" as opposed to delete them from the list.

Comment: Your code works if sex[2:3] == 'F' is changed to                                                   if sex[2:3] != 'F', please make this edit so that I can upvote your  answer.

Comment: Hey, do you have any other way that I can contact you? I have a few more questions and would compensate you for your time.

Comment: Or just email me artur1992@gmail.com